# О слове "злосчастный"

Tags: этимология

Злосчастный — это, как я понимаю, невезучий. Но как-то не вяжутся по смыслу два корня этого слова: "зло" и "счастье". Почему такое сочетание?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не знаю наверняка, но могу предположить, что слово "счастье" раньше имело более общее значение -- судьба, участь вообще, не только хорошая, но и плохая, "злая". Вот и было такое слово с конкретизацией, какое именно "счастье" у данного человека.
(Большой толковый словарь меня [поддерживает](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F1%F7%E0%F1%F2%FC%E5&all=x), давая и в современном языке одно из значений слова "счастье": "Разг. Участь, доля, судьба". Правда, примеры у него странные...)